# Change the color of the terminal

Tags: command-line

Guys when I log in to Shell Prompt I want to change the text colors to green if its that possible? I do not have any idea about doing it.

Comment: Do you want just the shell prompt colour to be changed or all text in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up in your .bashrc

```
export PS1="\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[1;32m\]@\\[\033[1;32m\]\h \[\033[1;32m\]\w \[\033[1;32m\]\$ \[\033[1;32m\]"
```

the result will be a green prompt :)